# Spring boot tests - run tests 2 time with different application-xxx.properties each time

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app that has tests for database stuff and I'm supporting mysql and mssql.

I have `src/text/resources/application-mysql.properties` and `src/text/resources/application-mssql.properties`

What environment variable can I set when I run my tests to tell Spring which *test* properties file to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property files in the format `application-*.properties` are activated using Spring Profiles. Same thing for YAML files, by the way! It is important to know that `application.properties` is still loaded first and any profile-specific properties will overwrite previously loaded properties (kind of the whole point of Spring Profiles).

There are multiple ways to enable profiles:

1. To answer your question, you can set the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable to enable profiles. For example, `export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=mysql`. You can also specify multiple profiles (and they are loaded in the same order) by separating them with a comma: `export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=localdefaults,local`.
2. You can also use the JVM parameter, `spring.profiles.active`. The value follows the same format as that of the environment variable. For example, `-Dspring.profiles.active=mysql`.
3. You can use the `@ActiveProfiles` annotation on your test class. For example:

```java
// Other annotations...
@ActiveProfiles("mysql")
public class MyTest {
```

4. If you want to enable profiles during a build, you can set the `spring.profiles.active` property in Maven. For example:

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>mysql</id>
    <properties>
      <spring.profiles.active>mysql</spring.profiles.active>
    </properties>
  </profile>
  ...
</profiles>
```

5. Here's a weird one I recently learned. You can also set active profiles with the `spring.profiles.active` in a properties file. I imagine this has its uses, but have never used this approach.

Read more about everything I have covered:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.properties-and-configuration
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html